# Geocoding not working on php mysql submission form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**What I want to happen:** User inputs customer data (name,address, etc) on a form, hits the submit button and that users info is updated to a msql database table. There is also a map page that calls on the mysql database and updates the map (not included in the code because that page works fine).

**The issue:** Gecode on this page isn't working. I want to have the lat/lng geocoded and saved to the table at the same time as the rest of the information so that if they go to the map screen next, there will be an updated marker at the address saved on this page.  As it stands right now the lat and lng fields always show 0.000000, without any errors being reported. What am I doing wrong?

**My code (saved as index.php):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
</TITLE>

<style>
body {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

table {
border-spacing: 0.5rem;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 0.2rem;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
/* Firefox 18- */
text-align: center;

}

::-moz-placeholder {
/* Firefox 19+ */
text-align: center;

}

:-ms-input-placeholder {

text-align: center;

}
.a {
background-color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
border-radius: 25px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 10px;

width: 80%;

}
.b {
background-color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
border-radius: 25px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 10px;

width: 80%;

}
img {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
border-radius: 25px;
}
.h  {
width: 80%;

margin-left: auto;

margin-right: auto;
height: 10px;
background: url(hr.png) no-repeat center;
border: none;
}

</style>
<link rel="icon" 
type="image/png" 
href="Icon2.png" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
<img class"i" src="companyname.png">
<p>
<h2>
Customer Control Panel 
</h2>


<div class="a" id="add_customer">
<form id="customerdata" name="customerdata" method="post" onsubmit="geoCode()">
<input type="text" align="center" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Customer Name">
<input type="text" align="center" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address">
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<b>
Paid?:
</b>
&nbsp
<select id="type" name="type">
<option value="select">
Make a Selection
</option>
<option value="Yes">
Yes
</option>
<option value="No">
No
</option>
<option value="Not">
Not a customer
</option>
</select>
<input type="text" align="center" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comments. Limited to 150ch">
<input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add Customer">
</form>
</div>

<!-- Start of PHP FORM SUBMITION -->

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
sleep(3);
include 'db.php';
$con = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mysql_db", $con);         
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
$lat= $_POST['lat'];
$lng= $_POST['lng'];
$type= $_POST['type'];
$comments= $_POST['comments'];
$sql= "INSERT INTO `mysql_table`(name,address,lat,lng,type,comments) VALUES ('$name','$address','$lat','$lng','$type','$comments')";
$a=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<br/><br/>";
if (!$a)

die("Error adding record: " . mysql_error());

else

echo "<br>"."1 record added";
}
?>
<!-- End of PHP FORM SUBMITION -->



<!-- Start of Customer viewing Table -->
<br>
<hr class="h">
<p>

<br>
<br>

<div class="b">
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr align="center">
<td>
<b>
Name
</b>
</td>
<td>
<b>
Address
</b>
</td>
<td>
<b>
Paid?
</b>
</td>
<td>
<b>
Comments
</b>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
include 'db.php';
$con = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db);

if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("mysql_db", $con);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `address`,`lat`,`lng`,`type`,`comments` FROM `my_table` WHERE 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

$name = $row['name'];
$address = $row['address'];
$lat = $row['lat'];
$lng = $row['lng'];
$type = $row['type'];
$comments = $row['comments'];
$name = htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
$comments = htmlspecialchars($row['comments'],ENT_QUOTES);

echo "<tr align='left'><td>$name</td><td>$address</td><td>$type</td><td>$comments</td></tr>";
}
mysql_close($db);
?>
</table>
<!-- End of Customer viewing Table -->

</div>
</center>

<script>
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
});
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
} else {
alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}
});
}
</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**EDITED 8/21/15**

I updated the code section to reflect what I have found on the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple).  Originally I had the geocode script in the `<head>` but according to the google example it goes in the body.  I was able to get the example code to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Geocoding service</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html, body {
height: 80%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#map {
height: 100%;
}
#panel {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 25%;
z-index: 5;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #999;
text-align: center;
}


#panel, .panel {
font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
line-height: 30px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

#panel select, #panel input, .panel select, .panel input {
font-size: 15px;
}

#panel select, .panel select {
width: 100%;
}

#panel i, .panel i {
font-size: 12px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="panel">
<input id="address" type="textbox" value="">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="lat"></div>
<div id="lng"></div>
<p>


<script>
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 12,
center: {lat: 32.2209784, lng: -110.8833395}
});
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
});
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: resultsMap,
position: results[0].geometry.location
});
} else {
alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}
});
}

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it's calling the address from within the map, I want to call the address from the form, which I thought wouldn't really matter as long as the names and id's were correct but I still can't seem to get my code to work right.  With the sample code I was able to write the lat and lng to separate `<div>` tags so I know that the geocode is working.  Could it be that my file is saved as a .php?

Answer (score 2):

The values of your `INSERT` statement doesn't match to the fields. There are 4 fields but you are passing 6 values.

Please change

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO `my_table`(name,address,type,comments) VALUES ('$name','$address','$lat','$lng','$type','$comments')";
```

to

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO `my_table`(name,address,type,comments) VALUES ('$name','$address','$type','$comments')";
```

OR you have to add the fields for the coordinates to your field list.

--

It looks like you are not using the variables `lat` and `lng` in your `geoCode` function. You should add two hidden inputs to your HTML form by adding

```
<input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng" value="" />
```

and using

```
document.getElementById('lat').value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById('lng').value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

in your `geoCode` function.

Comment: I corrected the INSERT INTO error in my code above. I realized that I hadn't changed it on my "scratch copy", which is what I copied and pasted into here. I've attempted to implement the additions you suggested but I still don't get the lat and lng saving to the table, and still no errors, so it seems as if the geocoding is working but not saving the values.  I'm going to play around with just trying to write the values directly to a '<div>' tag to see if is in fact returning the values.

Comment: Ok, please keep me up to date ;-) You can also try to call `alert(results[0].geometry.location.lat());` and `alert(results[0].geometry.location.lng());` to check if the geocoder is fetching the correct coordinates.

Comment: This is interesting, and it works. I got it from **[HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)**
I'm still playing around with tweeking it to work for my code.

Comment: It isn't working because of something to do with the form. When you run the Google Geocode example the address input textbox is contained within the map.  If you get rid of all the "panel" code and the `<div>` for it and add in a form with a submit button it no longer works. Even though the listener is still in place.  I don't get it.

Comment: I think I have an idea of how to implement this to work the way I want it to. I'm going to move the php code for inserting the data into the table into it's own page and then call on it using the form method `action="URL"` I'll post an update once I actually do it.